# Is this possible with android/bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

So I'm considering writing a bluetooth app for android, I'll need the following functionality:

- Auto-enabling bluetooth
- Broadcasting that the app is enabled to other phones with the same app running
- Listing other phones in proximity with app installed
- Sharing data between phones

Is all of this possible? I'm entirely new to bluetooth, what I really need to know is if I can do all this without forcing users to manually pair their devices or anything like that. So, for example, I'd like to do something along the lines of the following flow:

- Person A opens the app, sees a list of people nearby with the app enabled and running.
- Person A selects person B within the app, types in a message, presses "send"
- Person B receives the message

That's a simplified example of what I'm hoping to do -- is bluetooth the right tool for this / is this possible?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you need to use Discoverable Mode automatically?

Comment: Dan S: Yep, I imagine so; unless there's any other way to broadcast the existence of a phone with my app installed?

Comment: That'll be a problem afaik you can't put the phone in discoverable mode without user intervention. Wifi Direct (Peer to Peer Wifi) may be a better option.

Comment: @bluepnume i'm doing the same thing in my app....did u find any solution doing with bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

Yes for "Auto enabled Bluetooth".

No for "Broadcasting that ..." because you don't broadcast with Bluetooth (other then during discovery).

No for "Listing other phones in proximity with app installed" because having your app installed does not cause it's service to be listed.  It must be running for that (I hope they will change this).

Yes for sharing data between phones, and YES for the three bullet summary of what you want to do, but...

"what I really need to know is if I can do all this without forcing users to manually pair their devices or anything like that."

That is a common request and support for Bluetooth without pairing was added in 2.3 (it was hidden in 2.2).  Unfortunately, it is partially broken in ICS, up to and including 4.04 so the bug will be on all ICS devices:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29039

I think Bluetooth has a lot of potential, but I am finding that there are lots of bugs and lots of variability in the implementations so approach with caution.

Comment: Hurm, yeah, sounds like it may not be the tool for the job. I may have to look into other possibilities. Although I should clarify, I meant people with the app running rather than just installed.